# Is it possible to get all elements which have a specific value into any type of attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-attributes

I want to get all elements in an HTML Dom, which have any attribute with the a specific value.

For Example -

```
<ul style="width:150px;" id="RadioButton1">
   <li style="width:150px;"><input type="radio" name="RadioButton1"><label>Option 1</label></li>
   <li style="width:150px;"><input type="radio" name="RadioButton1"><label>Option 2</label></li>    
   <li style="width:150px;"><input type="radio" name="RadioButton1"><label>Option 3</label> </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get all elements which contains "RadioButton1" in any attribute. Means i want to select `UL` and all three `RadioButtons`.

**Note: Above HTML i used `UL-LI` structure, but the real scenario it's too much different. So please don't give answer in completely favor of `UL-LI`. I want global solution.**

There are any selector exist to select all type of attribute?

Is it possible to select elements with in this approach?

Bunch of Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Ok. Look at the following answers will help you

Comment: What Exactly mean by global solution....

Comment: @Sadikhasan: I am not want to use one or more attribute selectors. Want to select all attribute(like wild card selectors *).

Comment: @DovnVoter: Can you please tell me the reason for down vote here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by filtering each element and checking its attributes:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXv6D/)

```
var elements = $('*').filter(function () {
    return $(this.attributes).filter(function(){
        return this.nodeValue == 'RadioButton1'; 
    }).length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("*").each(function() { //check all elements inside DOM
    var elem = $(this);
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
      if(this.value=='RadioButton1'){
          console.log(elem); //your code goes here. elem is nothing but element 
                               //with value RadioButton1 in any attribute
      }
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** check console for elements.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/Q3JP4/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The attributes property contains them all:

```
$(this).each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
    // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
    if(this.specified) {
      if(this.value == 'RadioButton1')
      {
           alert(this.name);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[name='RadioButton1'],ul[id='RadioButton1']")
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, But as i described in question "I am looking for a global solution".

Comment: I am not want to use one or more attribute selectors. Want to select all attribute(like wild card selectors *).

Answer (score -2):

`$('[name="RadioButton1"]')` will select all items that have "RadioButton1" as their `name` attribute.

`$('[id="RadioButton1"]')` will select all items that have "RadioButton1" as their `id` attribute. Keep in mind that in case of ID attributes, there should only be one item with any given ID.

`$('[name="RadioButton1"],[id="RadioButton1"]')` will give you the combined list.

**Keep in mind that an item that has both the ID and Name attribute set to "RadioButton1" will be added twice.**

If there is a third attribute on which you want to search, just add that one to the comma-separated list of selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your support, But as i described in question "I am looking for a global solution".

Comment: Quote from your question: `please don't give answer in completely favor of UL-LI. I want global solution.` Please explain how this answer is specific to `<ul>` or `<li>` elements.

Answer (score -2):

To achieve this you should play with data-types="RadioButton"

And then using

```
$('input[data-types=RadioButton]')
```

Comment: Any randomly chosen attribute name might suffice, no? Assuming it starts with `data-`.